# How to make php print out results based on a given time

Tags: php

Is there a way to make php print out some results based on a given time? Say I tell it to

`echo"BEANS";`

at 12:00pm tomorrow.

Comment: What if no one visited the page at 12:00pm? What if someone visited the page at 12:00:01pm?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PHP web applications are meant to run for only a few seconds to a couple of minutes. Start a cron job to run that PHP script @12pm. On Windows, use Task Scheduler.

Comment: Yep, this is your answer... +1